Problem when overloading C++ operator - creating a char buffer but its size is too large and is garbage when output
I'm studying C++ through a Udemy course and have run into an odd issue with overloading the * operator.
In Main, the code is:
S1 = S2 * 3; //S1 is a Class with a single pointer to a char array.

The problem is that I'm trying to create a buffer of a specific size and load it with specific contents.  When I send the contents of the buffer to the console, there seems to be 5 or sometimes 10 bits of garbage on the end of the buffer, and the constructor doesn't work right, it just outputs garbage.  The std::cout's are just me trying to make sure each step is working correctly.
It all looks great until the final step, when I send the contents of the buffer to the console.  The buffer is always larger than what I expect, and there is garbage data on the end.
Any help!?
Here is the code in my class.cpp file:
//Repeat Operator
Mystring &Mystring::operator*(int x){
    
    int size = std::strlen(str);
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    std::cout << size * x << std::endl;

    int what = size * x;
    std::cout << what << std::endl;

    char* buff = new char[what+1];

    //std::cout << std::strlen(buff) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < std::strlen(str); y++) {
            //std::cout << str[y] << std::endl;
            buff[std::strlen(str)*i + y] = str[y];
            std::cout << buff[std::strlen(str)*i+y] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < std::strlen(buff); i++)
        std::cout << buff[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Mystring temp{ buff };
    delete[] buff;
    return temp;
}

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 v17.7.4.


The operator should be declared const.



Mystring should have a size member. Calling std::strlen() is not optimal.



buff is missing the null terminator. If you used std::vector, you would not make such silly mistake.


int size = std::strlen(str); -- But then you call std::strlen(str); over and over again in a for loop.  You should just be using size.  You do realize that strlen has to count from the beginning of the string, all the characters until a null terminator is found?  Imagine doing that multiple times in a for loop on the same string.

@PaulMcKenzie You do realize that most compilers know that strlen() can be cached if the string isn't modified during the loop?

Recommended reading: What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?

When you pass buff to the constructor of MyString, does that constructor copy the buffer or does it assume it takes ownership of buff?   If the latter, the MyString returned to the caller will contain a dangling reference.

buff is missing the null terminator.
char* buff = new char[what+1];

Should be
char* buff = new char[what+1];
buff[what] = 0;

Or (because the entire code is not optimal)
char* buff = new char[what+1]{};


Alternatively, make Mystring's constructor accept an extra size parameter alongside the char*, eg: Mystring temp{ buff, what }; then you don't need a null terminator.
